# Install software on a Pirelli WiFi router

Tags: router, wireless-networking, installation

I’ve got a Pirelli WiFi router from my IP TV operator. I've also got the Administrator and PUser login information so i can log in into it using it's web service on port 8080 and change the configuration.

I am looking for something more. Is there any way i can install additional software on my router and how ? I've heard somewhere that it's possible to install software on some routers, and i would like to know if something like this is possible here ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously advise against doing this.  Under most providers' contracts, you don't own the router and are only leasing it.  If you edit things on the hardware, they might either

a) charge you

b) cut you off

Both of which are costly and annoying.